# Why is the Pair in System.Web.UI?

Tags: .net, class

To me at least, the Pair class is a very multi-purpose class.  So why did Microsoft put it into the System.Web.UI namespace?

Is there a reason that my tiny brain cannot comprehend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find a great reason.  It seems as though it was first created by the web team, so they made it in their namespace/assembly.  They also added a [LinkDemand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securityaction.linkdemand.aspx) for [AspNetHostingPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.aspnethostingpermission.aspx), which is unfortunate.

In terms of its "expected use," MSDN says

> [The **Pair** class] is a utility class that is used in various ways throughout ASP.NET, such as during page state management tasks or in configuration section handlers.
>   ...
>   The **Pair** class can be used in several ways in page state persistence implementations. The most common use is as a container for both the [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx) and [ControlState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister.controlstate.aspx) collections. In this case, the [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pair.first.aspx) property is used for [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx), and the [Second](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pair.second.aspx) for [ControlState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister.controlstate.aspx).

Comment: I've always had the impression this was an after thought, something the web.ui namespace team wanted, but didn't have the ability to put it into the system namespace.  It's something that's always eaten at me, and I was wondering if there is a logical reason that I couldn't see.

Comment: Silo'd development at it's worst :(

Answer (score 5):

It is used to serialize viewstate (along with its cousin Triplet).

I would guess that the reason they are not part of the base library (even though there is nothing ASP.NET-specific about them) is that they are not very useful since they are untyped.

To include untyped pair and triplet in the base library, might be seen as encouraging "typeless" programming.

A typed tuple might be useful, though (and I think F# has them). I think anonymous types covers most of the use cases for heterogenous tuples though.

Comment: I can understand why you might want to use it in a webapp, but why not make it available throughout the library?  For example, why can't I use it in a basic DLL?

Comment: @John MacIntyre: You can use it in a basic DLL, you just have to include a reference to the System.Web.UI assembly.

Comment: I realize that, but if the DLL was used for a console app for example, doesn't it seem odd to have a dependency to a web ui assembly?  Really shouldn't it just be in the System namespace?

Comment: @John MacIntyre: Yes, it does seem odd to have a dependency to a web ui assembly from a console app, but that's what you would need to do. Also, from @bdukes' answer, it looks like this isn't possible due to the AspNetHostingPermission LinkDemand.

Comment: @Giao - doesn't look like there is.

Comment: For its use in viewstate, readers might be interested in my answer to a question about viewstate, which explains how to hand-roll viewstate and controlstate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3865762/205245

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer the question directly, but in .NET 4 you can, and probably should, use [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387036.aspx).

To answer the question, I believe it was simply a mistake to put Pair in System.Web.UI and Microsoft has attempted to resolve this mistake with the introduction of the Tuple class.

Answer (score 0):

God forbid we should have a typed Pair that is lighter than a dictionary and can be embeeded in a typed list so that it is indexable :). Of course creating one of these is painless, but why.