# How to add persistent dynamic controls based on user input (not on initial page load)

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle, dynamic-controls

I am familiar with creating and persisting dynamic controls on the first load of a page and on subsequent postbacks but I am having trouble with the following ***user initiated*** scenario...

In my demo I have a placeholder, two buttons and a literal

```
<div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phResponses" runat="server" />
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" Text="Add" runat="server" OnClick="Add"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnInspect" Text="Inspect" runat="server" OnClick="Inspect"/>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Literal ID="litResult" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

I want the user to be able to click the add button to provide a response so I have...

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BuildControls();
}

protected void Add(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BuildControls();
}

protected void BuildControls()
{
    phResponses.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl { ID = "response_" + _Count.ToString() });
    _Count++;
}
```

_Count is a static member variable to enable me to have unique ids for the new controls. I realise I need to rebuild the dynamic controls on Page_Init but the problem is that I end up with 2 new Literal controls on every postback. Also if any Text property is put into the new controls it is lost when the controls are rebuilt.

So how do I avoid adding multiple controls and how do I persist newly added properties when rebuilding these controls?

I use the following to inspect the responses

```
protected void Inspect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var control in phResponses.Controls)
    {
        if (control is LiteralControl)
        {
            litResults.Text += "<p>" + control.Text + " : " + control.ID + "</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Which itself adds another unwanted control because of the rebuilding on Page_Init

Answer (score 0):

I'd not sure that I quite understand what you're asking, but it looks like you just want to ensure that `BuildControls` is only called once per lifecycle. You could do that by making the following changes:

1. Add a new `private bool _isControlsBuilt = false;`.
2. Change `Page_Init` to check `_isControlsBuilt` before calling `BuildControls`.
3. Set `_isControlsBuilt` to `true` within `BuildControls`.
4. Make sure that `BuildControls` occurs earlier in the [page lifecycle](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2004/07/04/172683.aspx) than `Page_Init`.

As for losing the values of controls on postback, it'll be that they're never hitting the viewstate. I'm not sure if it'd work, but my first guess would be to add a line to the end of `BuildControls` to call [`Page.RegisterRequiresControlState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerrequirescontrolstate.aspx):

```
protected void BuildControls()
{
    LiteralControl newLiteral = new LiteralControl { ID = "response_" + _Count };
    this.RegisterRequiresControlState(newLiteral);
    phResponses.Controls.Add(newLiteral);

    _Count++;
    _isControlsBuilt = true;
}
```

If that doesn't work (which might imply that it's the _view_state, not the _control_state that matters to you here), you may need to look at rolling your own viewstate. I wrote about how to do that in [my answer to #3854193](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854193/3865762#3865762), which you might find useful.